# Python stop recursion once solution is found

Tags: python, recursion, sum

I have a recursive function which tries to form a certain sum given a list of integers. The function works but it gives me all possible solutions. I want to break out of the recursive function once a solution is found. How can I do that? Below is the (pseudo-)code for the function:

```
function find_sum(list_of_integers, target_sum, partial_solution):
    if partial_solutions == target_sum:
        return True
    if partial_solution > target_sum:
        return

    for i in range(len(list_of_integers)):
        n = list_of_integers[i]
        remaining = list_of_integers[i+1:]
        find_sum(remaining, target_sum, partial_solution + n)
```

So I just want to know if the target_sum can be formed by the list of integers, I don't need all the solutions.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to check the return value of the recursive call; if `True` is returned, propagate that immediately rather than continue to loop:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_integers)):
    n = list_of_integers[i]
    remaining = list_of_integers[i+1:]
    found = find_sum(remaining, target_sum, partial_solution + n)
    if found:
        return True
```

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the class. Initialize a variable self.flag=False in the **init** method, when you find the solution change self.flag = True and return None when self.flag is True.

```
class Solution:
    def __init__(self):
        self.flag = False

    def find_sum(....):
        for i in range(len(list_of_integers)):
             if self.flag: return True
             n = list_of_integers[i]
             remaining = list_of_integers[i+1:]
             self.flag = find_sum(remaining, target_sum, partial_solution + n)
```

Answer (score 0):

When you found the solution just return it, and use sys.exit(0) right in next line, it would stop further recursive calls and gets you out immediately.